# Running Dash Python from Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, plotly-dash

I'm having some problem with running a simple dash app from my spyder IDE.
I think that this comes from the new dash version 2.11.
When I execute the code below the standard message "Dash app running on [http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/"](http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/%22) is not shown.

```
from dash import Dash, html

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children='Hello Woraalssssd')
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This is the spyder snapshot:
[image]

am I missing something? (of course I do....)

Answer (score -1):

The problem you're experiencing may be due to the interaction between the Spyder IDE and Dash's development server. By default, Dash's development server is blocking. It will stop program execution at app.run_server(), and will not continue until the server is manually stopped.

Comment: But this is strange, in dash 2.7 the message was displayed.  I'm also experiencing other problems: for example, I usually add some print statement inside the callback as debug feature (to print values or types of variables) and now once the callback run the print is not shown in the console.